# Backup file is too large SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have database which is large 839 MB because there is a lot of images probably, and when I do next in my SQL Management Studio: right click on database -> Tasks -> Backup .. and after database is backed up MyBackup.bak file is 829 MB, shouldn't it be smaller? I need to upload my .bak file to another server and maximum upload size is like 250MB, so as you can see I have a problem.

So my question is how to decrease size of .BAK file on SQL Server.

Comment: "lot of images probably" -- you should definitely start by looking into your database and actually confirm what is there and how much space does it take. If your tables are compressed, take that into account too.

Answer (score 1):

In Back Up database wizard, try to set backup compression to **Compress backup**

> Right Click Database -> Tasks - > Back Up.. -> Backup Options -> Set
>   backup Compression -> Compress backup

**T-SQL**

```
BACKUP DATABASE databasename TO DISK='path\..'
WITH COMPRESSION
```

After taking backup check the backup size. If it is still not less than `250MB` then use any zip/compress application(`7zip,winzip,..`) present in windows to compress the backup file.

Comment: I got following error message after I selected Compress backuup  "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup cannot be performed because 'COMPRESSION' was requested after the media was formatted with an incompatible structure. To append to this media set, either omit 'COMPRESSION' or specify 'NO_COMPRESSION'. Alternatively, you can create a new media set by using WITH FORMAT in your BACKUP statement. If you use WITH FORMAT on an existing media set, all its backup sets will be overwritten. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)"

Comment: @Roxy'Pro - Change the backup path or the name of backup and try again

Comment: I changed path of backup location file, I mean i added new path so it created new backup not overriding old one, but that didn't help me a lot, its only 50MB smaller, instead of 829MB its like 780.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro - Then you have use a zip software to compress it.. try using 7zip or windows default compress software. From `SQL SERVER` I don't think any other option is present to compress the backup file.

Comment: I tried with WinRar. Final size is 400MB, its still better than 780MB but I need to lower it 150MB more to upload :// damnn :D

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Do you have 7zip ? that is quite powerful tool to compress

Comment: yes I use it, I didnt touch settings, I only  increased dictionary size to 1024MB and other stuffs are set to default..

Comment: I solved it by compressing it to 440MB and after that I separated that .rar in 4 files with like 100MB each and uploaded them one by one, and another solution was also to connect directly from sql to that server, and to migrate data (tables and data itself).

Answer (score 0):

```
-- If the database size too big better to go for Split backup so that it splits backup process and it will be faster
Use Master
Go
BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] 
TO  DISK = N'Your Path\DatabaseName_1.bak' ,
DISK = N'Your Path\DatabaseName_2.bak' ,
DISK = N'Your Path\DatabaseName_3.bak'-- You can split up to 'n' nmber of disk loactions depends od size of backup file
WITH NOFORMAT, 
NOINIT,  NAME = N'DatabaseName-Full Database Backup', 
SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 5
GO
```